# Overlapping tasks in Windows Service

Tags: c#, service

I have this windows service triggered after a specific time interval that does some task. However, while it is currently performing its task it is triggered again and the overlap causes some data to be overwritten. Following is the code segment that causes the overlap:

```
private Timer myTimer;
public Service1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void TimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    ITransaction transaction = new TransactionFactory().GetTransactionFactory("SomeString");


    transaction.ExecuteTransaction();

}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Set up a timer to trigger every 10 seconds.  
    myTimer = new Timer();
    //setting the interval for tick
    myTimer.Interval = BaseLevelConfigurationsHandler.GetServiceTimerTickInterval();
    //setting the evant handler for time tick
    myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerTick);
    //enable the timer
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
}

protected override void OnStop()
{

}
```

I want this overlap to stop.

Comment: So what do you want it to do, queue the jobs, or skip if its already processing?

Comment: Either would work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is simply to put all the coming transactions to a busy waiting until current task is completed. But in case if the tick time for your service trigger is small then skipping would also be fine. Following code changes might be sufficient:

```
    private Timer myTimer;
    private static Boolean transactionCompleted;
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        transactionCompleted = true;
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        //check if no transaction is currently executing
        if (transactionCompleted)
        {
            transactionCompleted = false;

            ITransaction transaction = new TransactionFactory().GetTransactionFactory("SomeString");


            transaction.ExecuteTransaction();

            transactionCompleted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing and wasit for the next tick
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Set up a timer to trigger every 10 seconds.  
        myTimer = new Timer();
        //setting the interval for tick
        myTimer.Interval = BaseLevelConfigurationsHandler.GetServiceTimerTickInterval();
        //setting the evant handler for time tick
        myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerTick);
        //enable the timer
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        //wait until transaction is finished
        while (!transactionCompleted)
        {

        }
        transactionCompleted = false;//so that no new transaction can be started
    }
```

**Note:** Changes in OnStop will let the current transaction to be finished when your service is stopped, rather then partially completed.

Comment: Actually that is the point of transactionCompleted so that it can stop multiple triggers not to happen.

Comment: Can you explain why have you changed the OnStop.

Comment: Yes i know, however its still not thread safe, and however unlikely will likely fail at some point and have 2 processes running at once.

Comment: @RattleSnake I have added a note related to the changes made to the OnStop.